# libxml2 xmlParseFile fails to load a well-formed XML

Tags: delphi, file, xml-parsing, delphi-xe, libxml2

Being new to libxml2 I am confused why xmlParseFile always returns nil

```
uses
  libxml2;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  doc: xmlDocPtr;
begin
  doc := xmlParseFile('1.xml'); // doc is nil
  doc := xmlParseFile('c:\1.xml'); // doc is again nil
end;
```

Sample 1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
</root>
```

The xml is reported to be well-formed by both XML Spy 2007 and xmllint tools.

I use the precompiled DLLs from http://xmlsoft.org and tries this code with both DelphiAPI-2.6.26 and libxml2-pas-2-7-3-src without luck.

I guess I am missing something?

The debugger just jumps over the line since it points to an external reference like this:

```
function xmlParseFile (const filename: PChar) : xmlDocPtr; cdecl; external LIBXML2_SO;
```

Comment: I have been using libxml2 in C++ for years without any problem, so I have to suspect that the Delphi binding for libxml2 likely has a problem in it.  How is `xmlParseFile()` declared in libxml2.pas? The real function expects a `PAnsiChar` as input. Is libxml2.pas declaring `xmlParseFile()` to use a `PAnsiChar`?  This is important in Delphi XE, where the native string types are Unicode and not Ansi.

Comment: You were right - changing the Delphi wrapper from PChar (which is PWideChar in XE and XE2) to PAnsiChar resolved the problem. Once the definition of the function was changed to function xmlParseFile (const filename: PChar) : xmlDocPtr; cdecl; external LIBXML2_SO; it worked fine. Remy please make you comment an answer which I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all credit going to Remy I will put the answer instead of him to have this closed:

Changing the Delphi wrapper from PChar (which is PWideChar in XE and XE2) to PAnsiChar resolved the problem. Once the definition of the function was changed to

```
function xmlParseFile (const filename: PWideChar) : xmlDocPtr; cdecl; 
external LIBXML2_SO;
```

it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I created project on github https://github.com/ak47morozov/Delphi-Libxml2.

Fixed a few encoding bugs on Delphi XE2. (PChar -> PAnsiChar)